# loading wordpress links into div using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, load

im trying to make my wordpress links load into a div instead of refreshing a page. have tried some tutorials out there on the net but they dont seem to work (or not completely)

my own tryout only pulls out my last post each time (it does get loaded into the div but it doesnt genereate other posts then the last so all links i click goto the same post.

anyone got an idea why this doesnt work ?

many thanks!

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="WZ-OVER-wereldTitle">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
    </div>


<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        var postID = $('.WZ-OVER-wereldTitle a').attr('rel');
        $('.WZ-OVER-wereldTitle a').click( function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#content').html('loading...');
            $('#content').load('http://www.weetzelf.nl/?p=' + postID);
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load external ( cross domain ) request using `.load`. It won't work.

Alternative: Use [James Padolsey plugin](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) and then call that. This works till jquery1.4.4 only

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YErfj/

Comment: thanks, ive solved this using the_permalink for loadedURL and the_ID to select the correct a.

actually now im trying to use your method to get back to main index page (im not sure i understand ajax gd enuff atm, u got a lil tip to make this work when i click a tag/cat? and use your plugin) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that you're doing wrong is here:

```
$('#content').load('http://www.weetzelf.nl/?p=' + postID);
```

What this does is load your content into your `#content` div. But jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method sets the entire content of its target to be whatever was returned from `load()`. That's why you're only getting the last post -- you're actually loading all the posts successfully, one after the other, with each new one replacing what you loaded the last time through.

Try something like

```
$('#content').append($('<div>').load('http://www.weetzelf.nl/?p=' + postID));
```

That will create a brand new `div` element, load the content into *that*, and append it to your #content, rather than replacing what's already there.

However, the other odd thing you're doing is outputting the jQuery part multiple times, because it's inside the php `while` loop. Because of this, I think you're going to end up with as many copies of that script as there are posts, all running on page load (one after the other.) Check the source of your site in your browser to see whether this is the case -- I'm guessing you'll see multiple copies of your `<script>` block.

To solve that, move the script part outside of the php `while` loop. You only need one copy of it.